# How to know if user click in "Cancel" UAC during initialization?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a NET Framework 4.5.2 in Inno Setup wizard, and i have a problem with Windows 8.1:

My C# application verify if Windows have NET Framework 4.5.2, and if dont, we call the instalation generated by Inno Setup and install with Silenty/Hidden options.
The problem is, if the user are not admin, and a UAC window open asking if he want do execute or not the application (from Inno Setup). If user click on cancel, how i can know that the instalation dont have finished or dont even started ?
Theres a way to know if he have cancel without looking if NET Framework are in registry/regedit ? I say that, because on Windows 8.1 the Release version from NET Framework are only updated after reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

[Inno Setup-made installer returns exit code 2](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes), when it did not finish for whatever reason (including UAC cancel).

Though I'm not sure why you need to check for UAC cancel specifically. You want to know, if the installation failed for any reason, right? So check for any non-zero exit code.